# Error in starting new project in Django

Tags: python, django

So I am starting up with Django. I installed python, and when I run python in the CMD, it runs well. Next, I downloaded and installed Django, went into the python shell, imported django and outputed its version successfully. Finally I made a new directory for my project, entered:

django-admin.py startproject mysite

and I got the following error:

```
Type 'django-admin.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runserver
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured 

(error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either

define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).
```

Did I do something wrong in Django's installation?

Comment: are you using virtualenv?

Comment: No. The book I am following didn't introduce it yet.

Comment: Okay so a strange thing happened. I removed the .py accidentally and the project was created. Is the .py a typo in the book?

Comment: no, you need `virtualenv` because you may *run into dependency issues between your applications and the installed packages*, here try this [tutorial](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/), and I will suggest you to use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for you're `virtualenvironment`, understand that first, then install `django`

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look now. Thanks.

Comment: @PetarP Even if I support you 100% with using virtualenv, its not a solution for the question ;) But not using a virtualenv is a sign, that the book might be not as good as it might be.